icinga2 api seems slow, between 0.15 and 0.25 seconds response time Anyway to improve this?
We are using icinga as a service status service. We only have passive checks which are updated using the API interface.
When certain machines are turned on, a bulk of service updates are sent, around 34k. These updates are buffered and sent to icinga to have the statusses updated.
The response time for any request is around 0.2 seconds on average. Which is way too long. Doing some updates parallel does help, but it is not the answer and there seems to be a limit on the parallel processing.
What can we do to speed up this api processing? Is this a normal duration, as in 'this is the design' of icinga?
Nothing else is being done on these services. The 34k updates appear less then once a month.
Any thoughts on the performance?
We tried running it parallel, but more then 4 concurrent api request did not improve the overall handling. (We have 4 cpu's that are not really working that hard)
